# Decryption failed because the HMAC could not be validated - error on Migration d2d dashboard page

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm trying to migrate Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 with Migrate d2d module. Problem is that I get 2 errors on Migrate dashboard page:

```
Decryption failed because the HMAC could not be validated.
Migration c9b87f5afFile could not be constructed.
```

And they are repeating many times. I can run migrate process, but custom defined field values are not migrated since I didn't map them. I can't access field mapping page because of this error.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will help you, but I ran into this error while using webforms:

> Decryption failed because the HMAC could not be validated.

My issue was I tried to encrypt a webform field after there was already unencrypted data saved for that field in the database. So when I tried to view the results of my webform, I would get the above error because it was trying to decrypt data that was not encrypted.

Perhaps this is what is happening when you try to migrate?

My solution was to manually clear the data from the database. Once I did that, I was able to get to the webform results page in the drupal admin and clear the data from there to be sure all evidence of it was gone. Because I am in development this was an ok solution.

I am guessing clearing the data will not work for you, but perhaps this will help point you in the right direction.

Comment: I was using Migrate gui, so I'm not sure what happen under the hood. But solution for this was that I started whole process from beginning and it worked then. Somehow, at some step some error occur and intermediate data was corrupted somehow.